# spymemcached next unique key from cache

Tags: java, unique-key, spymemcached

Is it possible to get auto generated unique key using spymemcached API?

I would like to use something like this:

```
String key = memcachedClient.add("Some data");
//key - auto generated next unused key
```

So, if it's impossible can I use some kind of sequences to get next unused key?

Regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 1):

A unique key is given by an hash function ([Wiki-hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)). An hash function for  different inputs gives  (very) different outputs. 
So if you want a method that gives you a unique key try to implements an hash function. try to look for MD5  SHA1... there are a lot  of algorithm..

Comment: thanks for your answer, as I know, it is possible that hash from different text can be the same. It is the critical point in my application. I think, that this problem solution should be related to spymemcached.

Comment: that depends on how much the algorithm used is immune to collisions. A collision, in few word, is the probability that an hash is repeated. for example MD5 is 128bit so 2^128 possible combination. But there are algorithm that use 256 bit or more...